# Is there anyway for SQL Server Profiler to remember column widths?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I've setup SQL Server Profiler to only report events relevant to me and it works great.  However, I think what sucks is that it doesn't remember the column widths.  I could set them up properly and save it as a Profiler template, but the next time I start a trace, it forgets the column widths.

Is there a trick or am I missing something simple or does it simply not save these values?

Comment: AFAIK, it doesn't save the layout. Give that [this bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/455337/clicking-clear-trace-window-resets-column-widths) existed, even if it was saved, it would have been reset to defaults anyway. +1 for optimism, though, because it would be nice to have.

Comment: I wish. I'd actually say this is one of my number one feature requests for that product... but I know of no way to preserve column widths, and in fact, every time you filter, it resets them anyway.  Very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I am certain this feature does not exist. I recommend you request a new feature, seems like many people would vote for it.

[Here is the link to reach out to the SQL Team and suggest it.](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer)

Comment: Given that it is deprecated it is extremely unlikely to be worthwhile suggesting this.

Comment: It appears that SSMS v17.3 added XEvent Profiler to supersede SQL Server Profiler.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/use-the-ssms-xe-profiler